# Problems with running JUnit4 Parameterized test in Eclipse 3.6

Tags: eclipse, ant, junit4

I am trying to run parameterized test, but it even doesn't start. I found that it happens when I added constructor in TestClass (it is required for parameterized test). I successfully run my test via ant. But it's to complicated to debug. Eclipse version is 3.6 SR2 Win64

Comment: I found answer: it is possible to run a test class, but not test method. It seems to me that it is restriction of Junit

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it.